# make shell commands available in git hook

Tags: git, sh, githooks

The goal is to make some set of commands available to the user after they clone/checkout repo.

the git hook file

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $PWD/dev-commands.sh
source $PWD/dev-commands.sh
```

the command I want to make available after the git hook names dev-commands.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
function greet() {
  echo Hello
}
```

this does not seem to make the command available. if I run source dev-commands.sh in the directory manually it does make the `greet` commands availble..

any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourced functions are available in the shell that sourced them, not its parent shells. That's why when you write a shell script, it can use its own functions without worrying about interfering with what its invoker's commands mean.

```
( doit() { echo hi; }; doit ); doit
```

for instance, will say `hi` and then very probably complain `-bash: doit: command not found` or an equivalent message because the parens were there to put `doit` into a subshell, which has its own environment, just like git hooks.

Altering someone's shell namespace on the fly without their active cooperation can and will be accurately described as malware.

Include a setup command they can source if they want.

Comment: okay I see what you mean. so you can't really force them to run scripts on a hook - instead, use the hook to tell them to run a certain shell commands that makes everything available.

ultimately I want them to have a bunch of easy commands available for different configs and whatnot, so this makes sense

Comment: My usual is to supply makefile targets for the setup stuff. `make setup` is pretty easy to remember, and it can do anything you want. You can even suggest they say `make -n setup` to see what it'll do.

Comment: Note that bash in particular has a "feature" where you can export a function to an unrelated sub-shell via environment variables. (Bash encodes the function as text, and the sub-shell then scans the text and re-creates the function.) This has some nasty security implications, so one might hope the default is to have it disabled...